# Find convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-ln(n)}$

Tags: convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-ln(n)}$$
I was comparing it to $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$
and I had limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$$
where $${a_n}=\frac{1}{n^2-ln(n)}$$ and $${b_n}=\frac{1}{n^2}$$
but at the end I have that series diverges, but it should converge instead.

Thanks for helping in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It would be helpful if you could explain exactly why you are stuck and what else you tried.

Comment: I'm stuck because I have a mistake,but I can't find it.Something is wrong with limit that I have.
I tried to solve it using calculator,but it said that this series is convergance and I'm so confused by it.

Comment: Do you know whether $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges or diverges?

Comment: it should converges,cause it's Dirichlet's series p=2,so p>1 ig

Comment: Why do you think $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-ln(n)}$ diverges? Please include your answer to my question in the body of your question, not in the comments.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I change it,I hope it'll help a bit

Comment: Here's a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496626/investigate-the-convergence-of-the-series?noredirect=1) just like yours and it has an answer that may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each positive integer $ n \geq 2 $, we have $ \ln{n} < n $, and thus $$ \frac{1}{ n^2 - \ln{n} } < \frac{1}{ n^2 - n } = \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}. $$ And we have $$ \sum_{ k = 2 }^n \left( \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k} \right) = 1 - \frac{1}{n} ,$$
so $$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{ n^2 - n } = 1 .$$
Finally, we have
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ n^2 - \ln{n} } \\
=& 1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{ n^2 - \ln{n} } \\
\leq& 1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{ n^2 - n } \\
=& 2.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Despite the upvotes and the acceptance of your answer, this doesn't answer OP's specific question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you were trying to use the [limit comparison test (LCT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $${a_n}=\frac{1}{n^2-ln(n)}$$ and $${b_n}=\frac{1}{n^2}.$$

It seems that, for some reason you haven't told us, upon application of the LCT you ended up showing that the series diverges. But this is not true, and so you must have made a mistake before you concluded that the series diverges. Since you haven't shown us your working that made you conclude that the series diverges by the LCT, we cannot yet help show you where you went wrong in your working. However, I can show you how the LCT does indeed show that the series converges.

Since $a_n\geq 0, b_n\geq 0\quad \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ $ and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2}{n^2-ln(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) n^2}{\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\left(n^2-ln(n)\right)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{1-\frac{ln(n)}{n^2}} = 1,$$

correct usage of the LCT tells us that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges $\ \iff \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges. I'm assuming you already know and can use the result that $ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. We can therefore conclude by LCT that $ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.